# How to have one domain serving frontend and backend?

Tags: heroku, dns, netlify

Let's say I purchase the domain: "www.myapp.com".
I'm planning to run a headless CMS on heroku and a Vue js frontend on netlify.
How can I use the same domain for both apps?
I would like something like this:

- Backend: "backoffice.myapp.com"
- Frontend: "www.myapp.com"

Is it possible with 1 domain? How do I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your domain provider panel you create backoffice.myapp.com subdomain and point CNAME record to heroku. And you set a CNAME record for [www.myapp.com](http://www.myapp.com) to netifly.

Instructions:

[Netifly](https://docs.netlify.com/domains-https/custom-domains/configure-external-dns/#configure-a-subdomain)

[Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-custom-domain-with-a-subdomain)